# ColReorder DT extension in combination with shinyjqui

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, shiny, dt

My aim is to display some data tables and:

1) enable columns reaordering for all tables

2) enable chaning tables order.

My first try was using `shinyjqui::jqui_sortable` in combination with `DT::datatable`.

For columns reordering, the `ColReorder` extension does a great job, e.g.

```
library(DT)
datatable(mtcars,
          extensions = c("ColReorder"),
          options = list(colReorder = TRUE))
```

However, after adding interactions using `jqui_sortable`, columns reordering does not work any more:

```
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tb <-renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars,
              extensions = c("ColReorder"),
              options = list(colReorder = TRUE))
  })

  output$gg <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg, color = factor(vs))) + 
      geom_point() + 
      theme(legend.position= "none")
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  jqui_sortable(div(plotOutput('gg', width = '200px', height = '200px'),
                    dataTableOutput('tb', width = '200px', height = '200px')
                    ))
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'd be grateful for any ideas how to fix it or propositions of another approach :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `options` argument to `jqui_sortable` function: `options = list(cancel = '.dataTables_scroll')`. In this case it cancels sorting functionality on elements with class `.dataTables_scroll` which is whole table (with column names).